# Query string lost when using Web Forms routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I'm trying to route to the following pages with query strings:

```
http://sitename/Pages/Pages.aspx?id=1 - route to - http://sitename/testpage1  
http://sitename/Pages/Pages.aspx?id=2 - route to - http://sitename/testpage2
```

I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls in a webform project:

```
var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.MapPageRoute("News Default", "News", "~/news/news.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Contact Default", "Contacts", "~/contacts/contacts.aspx");

routes.MapPageRoute("Test1", "TestPage1", "~/Pages/Pages.aspx?id=1");
routes.MapPageRoute("Test2", "TestPage2", "~/Pages/Pages.aspx?id=2");
```

The News Default and Contact Default work fine but not the testpages, which lose the query string value.

Comment: When you say "but not the testpages", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: If I enter `http://sitename/testpage1` it uses `http://sitename/Pages/Pages.aspx` but loses the querystring value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a default value for the route. May not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Test2", "TestPage2/{id}", "~/Pages/Pages.aspx", true, 
new RouteValueDictionary {{"id","2"}});
```